# Link not sending back on a sharex custom uploader

Tags: javascript

I made a custom uploader on Glitch and it won't send the link back to Sharex (it gets saved on the server).

Here's the response part:

```
response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
response.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, file: { url: \`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/i/${newFileName}\`, delete_url: \`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/delete?filename=${newFileName}&key=${request.body.key}\`
```

I have tried this:

```
console.log(response.send(JSON.stringify({ success: true, file: { url: \`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/i/${newFileName}\`, delete_url: \`http://${process.env.PROJECT_DOMAIN}.glitch.me/delete?filename=${newFileName}&key=${request.body.key}\`)
```

and got this:

```
{"success":true,"file":{"url":"http://block-is-a-virgin.glitch.me/i/Pztga80D.png","delete_url":"http://block-is-a-virgin.glitch.me/delete?filename=Pztga80D.png&key=goawayandleavemykeyalone"}}
```

Let me know if you need any more code to indentify the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out it was a client side error.
The response thing wasn't set right and it didn't know how to grab out the url.